# After using firebase email update API how do I reuse the old email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**UPDATE:** it just randomly started working for me now...is there a period of time after updating an email that it is ineligible for new account creation?

I was able to use this API call provided by firebase to change emails for an account, but now I cannot use the other email to create a new count. I cannot reuse the other email at all. It seems like there is still a lock or hold on the old email.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateEmail

Steps to reproduce error

1. signup with **original@email.com**
2. update account email to  **new@email.com** (and click verification link sent via email)
3. cannot create a new account (nor re-update existing account) with **original@email.com**

I am simply looking to free up the email that is no longer in use. (original@email.com)

Note in image below that 'original@email.com' does not show up
[image]

Comment: Did you click the revoke email change link?

Comment: @bojeil no i did not

Answer (score 4):

This is a security related behavior. The old email is reserved just in case the owner of the email decides to revert to the old account by clicking the email change revocation link which is sent to the old email. This gives the owner of the account the ability to recover their account in case it was hijacked and the attacker tried to change their email.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil, is this actually documented anywhere in firebase documentation? and does it say or do you know how long the email is reserved if so?

Comment: This makes so much sense, thanks a lot! I couldn't find it anywhere in the Firebase documentation